# How to limit the number of ids selected in JSON extractor?

Tags: jmeter

I have been able to get the id of all the fields using the `JSON extractor` in Jmeter with the following query:

`$..MetaInputList.*.DocumentElementMetaInputId`

[image]

But I want to get the limited number of random ids, let's say 4, 0r 5 ids in `documentElementMetaInputId`.

The ids are selected as:

```
documentElementMetaInputId_1=1398
documentElementMetaInputId_10=1407
documentElementMetaInputId_11=1408
documentElementMetaInputId_12=1409
documentElementMetaInputId_13=1410
documentElementMetaInputId_14=1411
documentElementMetaInputId_15=1412
.....so on.
```

How can I do that using JSON extractor? further, I want to use that list of ids in another request.

```
{
  "documentElementMetaInputIdList": [
    //list of ids
  ]
}
```

Updated JSON structure.

```js
{
    "Sections": [{
        "Row": "R0",
        "Disable": true,
        "Cols": [{
            "Column": "c0",
            "Section": [{
                "Name": "Eclampsia - EmerCheck",
                "SectionElement": [{
                    "DocumentElementId": 47267
                }]
            }, {
                "Name": "Eclampsia - EmerCheck",
                "SectionElement": [{
                    "DocumentElementId": 47268
                }]
            }, {
                "Name": "Eclampsia - EmerCheck",
                "SectionElement": [{
                    "DocumentElementId": 47271,
                    "MetaInputList": [{
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3588
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3589
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3590
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3591
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3592
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3593
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3594
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3595
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3596
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3606
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "Name": "Eclampsia - EmerCheck",
                "SectionElement": [{
                    "DocumentElementId": 47272,
                    "MetaInputList": [{
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3607
                    }, {
                        "DocumentElementMetaInputId": 3608
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "metaInformation": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can use [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) with [slicing feature](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#projections) to limit the result.

Your JMESPath expressions

```
$..MetaInputList.*.DocumentElementMetaInputId | [0:5]
```

[image]

Comment: this didn't work on my end i always get the output as default values

Comment: Can you paste a sample JSON response with a few IDs into the question? I could try the JMESPath expression in ViewResultTree listener.

Comment: Updated the answer with the correct syntax for the slicing. Please use `$..MetaInputList.*.DocumentElementMetaInputId | [0:5]`

Comment: I have updated the JSON structure.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after your JSON Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def list = new HashSet<>()

   1.upto(4, {
       while (list.size() != 4) {
           list.add(vars.get('documentElementMetaInputId_' + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, vars.get('documentElementMetaInputId_MatchNr') as int + 1)))
       }
   })

   def payload = [documentElementMetaInputIdList: list.collect { entry -> entry as int }]

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Use `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where you need the generated list of random IDs

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I tried but got error saying `org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script89.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61
`

Comment: I am using JMeter version 5.3 and java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)`, I also tried in JMeter 5.4.1, and still got same error.

Comment: You need to either downgrade your Java or upgrade the Groovy library in JMeter

Comment: How is Groovy upgraded? What is the way? I downloaded the zip file from here, `https://groovy.apache.org/download.html`. But don't know how to actually use it, what to copy to /lib folder of JMeter? I am running windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which could go with the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).
Add following into a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) just below the JSON Extractor to limit the IDs.

```
def lstIds = []
int idsToIncludeCount = 50
int idCount = vars.get("DocumentElementMetaInputId_matchNr").toInteger()
log.info("Total IDs count : ${idCount}")

if (idCount >0) {
    
    for (int i=1 ; i <= idCount; i++ ) {
        String IdReference = "DocumentElementMetaInputId_" + i 
        String currentId = vars.get(IdReference)
        lstIds.add(centreId)
        log.info("Current centre is ${currentId}")
    }

    lstIds = lstIds[0.. idsToIncludeCount]
    
}
```

[Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) is used for slicing the elements (IDs) from a list.

1. Assign the IDs into a list
2. Slice the list to limit the IDs

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution with the [For Each](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) controller.

The solution will work with your [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) result, `DocumentElementMetaInputId`

Add a For Each controller to iterate over the required number of IDs. You can set the starting and end indexes.

[image]

You can use `${DocumentElementMetaInputIdOut}` within the child controllers .

[image]